# AWS Code Deploy Expanding a war file issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have a springboot web application (java classes and a couple of html files) which I am storing on CodeCommit. I build it with maven and generate a war file. I created a code pipeline which builds a zip file of this war file and appspec.yml along with a couple of shell scripts and stores it on S3. What I would like to do in my appspec.yml is to copy the war file to a specific location. I tried the below in the files section

```yaml
files:
  - source: SpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war   
    destination: /home/ec2-user/SpringBootApp/war_files
```

which doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to create an expandApp.sh as below

```sh
cp SpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /home/ec2-user/SpringBootApp/
cd /home/ec2-user/SpringBootApp/
jar -xvf SpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

but the 1st line itself throws directory not found error.

Any idea how to make it work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure, that source file to be reffered as "SpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" rather than "target/SpringBootApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"

Comment: I would do that in the buildspec.yml file. The war is already part of the zip in S3 so when i unzip it, it doesn't go to a specific folder like target. In the code deploy on EC2, it gets copied to the deployment-archive folder. Also there is no error in relation to the files hook in the appspec.yml

Comment: I found the issue. It's the special characters on the .sh files because the files were edited on Eclipse on Windows. I needed to convert the delimiters to unix deploy. All good now. Thank you for all the attention!